# Using Regex to only allow certain characters in HTML input field seems not to work when starting with a not allowed character

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to only allow certain characters a user can type / copy into a HTML-`<input>` field by using following Regex:

```
return /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/.test(value);
```

It works for me properly, but only if I start with an allowed character (e.g.: "**A**").

However, if I am starting with a character which isn't allowed by my Regex (e.g.: "**!**"), I suddenly can type in characters which should be disabled:

[image]

For testing I have created following fiddle: [>>Click<<](https://jsfiddle.net/SteffPoint/b6n1qkm4/2/)

Full script as reference:

```
<input type="text" class="polarion-TextBox" name="targetDocument" style="width: 100%;">

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    window.setTimeout ( function() {  
    // Restricts input for the given textbox to the given inputFilter.
    function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
      ["input"].forEach(function(event) {
        textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
          if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
            this.oldValue = this.value;
            this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
            this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
          } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
            this.value = this.oldValue;
            this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
          }
        });
      });
    }

   // Restrict input to digits and '.' by using a regular expression filter.
  setInputFilter(document.getElementsByName("targetDocument")[0], function(value) {
  return /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/.test(value); 

  });

    }, 1000);


}, false);  
</script>
```

Comment: What if you try `/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g.test(value)`

Comment: Thanks your your comment. Unfortunately then I can type in disabled characters also after starting with an allowed character.

Comment: I can't type any non-allowed char when the field is empty in your fiddle.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome 77.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have an oldValue when you enter any character for first time, so your code won't go into your second condition
2. Once your first character doesn't match, whatever you type next, the value never goes into first condition so oldValue is never set and as there is no existing oldValue your code won't go into second condition.

You can have an initial oldValue to empty string to fix this issue.

Add `textbox.oldValue = "";` before `textbox.addEventListener`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```js
function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
  ["input"].forEach(function(event) {
    textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
          this.value = this.oldValue;
          this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
        } else {
          this.value = "";
          this.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
        }
      } else {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      }
    });
  });
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setInputFilter(document.getElementsByName("targetDocument")[0], function(
    value
  ) {
    return /[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g.test(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="polarion-TextBox" name="targetDocument" style="width: 100%;">
```

Main change is clearing out the `value` if there is no `oldValue` to restore on invalid input. I also inverted the logic and return `true` if there are any invalid characters.